# JS/CSS Slide effect works in fiddle, not in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

My first problem was about the fiddle not working. Now it works, but if I copy it into my brackets file it doesn't work anymore. I did include the link that I placed in the external resource.
Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wtbdxx2b/6/

And the html;

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="site3.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="site3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="trigger">
  click
</button>

<div class="content">
 hello
</div>



 </body>
</html>
```

the css;

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000; 
  color: #FFF;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.content.open {
   height: 90%; 
}
```

and the javascript;

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
    $(".content").toggleClass("open");
});
```

Comment: what does the `console` say?

Comment: it says nothing, nothing happens when I click the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
    $(".content").toggleClass("open");
});
```

Inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".trigger").click(function() {
        $(".content").toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: holy shit thank you! By the way, what's the best way to link jquery? With a link to the site or to the file on your pc (if you downloaded it)

Comment: That's why you should put your script tags before the end tag of <body> and you shouldn't add event listeners if it's not necessary

Comment: Say **why**. Just "do this" isn't a *useful* answer.